# Conditionally parsing an array based on previous elements with nom

Tags: parsing, rust, nom

I need to parse an array of 32 bit ints (little endian), from an array of u8s, however the next int only exists if the 31st bit of the current int is set. If the rest don't exist then the rest of the array should be set to zeroes. I'm not sure how to go about conditionally parsing the next element.

Lets say the field is 4 bytes long. Then the result of the parse_field function would be that the 4 bytes would be parsed with le_u32, and that would be the first element in the [u32; 8] array. If however, this field's 31st bit is set. Then there exists another 4 bytes that is also like this field and it goes in the next element in the array. If it is not set then the function must return, the array with the rest of the elements set to zero. And this continue for each existing field.

For example for the following input:

```
0x8000000a
0x8000000b
...
```

You would get `[0x8000000a, 0x8000000b, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]`

But if the input is

```
0x8000000a
0x8000000b
0x8000000c
0x8000000d
0x8000000e
....
```

Then you would get `[0x8000000a, 0x8000000b, 0x8000000c, 0x8000000d, 0x8000000e, 0, 0, 0]`

```
extern crate nom;

use nom::*;

#[derive(Clone, Copy, Debug)]
struct Derp {
    field: [u32; 8]
}

named!(parse_field<[u32; 8]>,

    // what do I do here

);


named!(parse_derp<Derp>,
    do_parse!(
        field: parse_field >>
        (Derp {
            field: field
        })
    )
);

fn main() {
    let temp = [0x0a, 0x00, 0x00, 0x80, 0x0b, 0x00, 0x00, 0x80];
    println!("{:?}", parse_derp(&temp));
}
```

Also is it possibly better to use a Vec here?

Comment: Do you have to use nom for this? Couldn't you just bitwise `& 2` your i32s in a loop until you hit a false?

Comment: cloud you please reformat your question, input more example for your case, i don't understand your question anyone.

Comment: I have updated the question. I have to use nom because this is part of a bigger parser. Maybe the best way is to manually write the parsing function that fits into nom.

Comment: Like something like `fn parse_field(i: &[u8]) -> IResult<&[u8], [u32; 8]> { .... }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a parser that matches the last `u32` of your input:

```
named!(last_u32<u32>,
  verify!(le_u32, |n:u32| (n & 0b1) != 0) // Matches iff the 31st bit is set
);
```

you can then use it like this:

```
named!(parse_field<Vec<u32>>,
  map!(
    many_till!(le_u32, last_u32),
    |(mut v,n)| { v.push(n); v } // Add the last u32 to the vector
  ) 
);
```